# avoid multiple bindings ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery

on select box change in modal panel. I am firing an ajax request and loading the modal panel data depends up on the response.

I am seeing initially only one request is firing at first attempt. but it's keep on increasing with the number of the times with the select option.

below is my script

```
$(".dds").msDropDown();
$('#dropdown').off('change');
$('#dropdown').on('change', takeAction);

function takeAction(event){
event.preventDefault();
var colour = $('#colors .selected').attr('data-color');
console.log(colour);
new Ajaxinator().jsonPost({
    url :$(event.currentTarget).val(),
    data : {
        name : $(event.currentTarget).attr('title'),
        colour : colour
    },
    success: function (response)
    {   
    $('#dropdown').off('change');

    $('#Data').html(response.Data);
    $('#dropdown').off('change',takeAction);

}
});

};
```

I am thinking that this is because of every ajax request the new binding is creating for  #dropdown and onchange function is calling multiple times. Can anyone help me out.

Comment: Not sure I understand what the problem is... your current code tells the browser to call the `takeAction()` function every time the dropdown changes (i.e. a new option is selected). Is that not what you want? Or is there another problem?

Comment: but these function is calling multiple times..initially when I change the dropdown it's calling only one time which is fine..when I again change the dropdown this function calling twice..and it keep on increasing

Comment: Hmmm, from what I can see, that shouldn't happen... perhaps the problem is in the HTML or another part of the Javascript? Also, what is .msDropDown() ? Is that a custom drop down? Maybe the problem is with that.

Comment: I have a modal panel in that modal panel I have a dropdown which is styled with dd plugin.When I select the dropdown it will generate an ajax request and will repaint the panel with the data in response. The above script will be a part of response data.this will also be  binded with every request.

Comment: Ah, try changing your success function to:

`success: function (response) { $('#dropdown').off('change');
$('#Data').html(response.Data); $('#dropdown').on('change', takeAction); }`

Comment: tired it same result..I will edit above script with your changes .Is that the one you are expecting.

Answer (score 0):

Can you give this a try?

```
var oAJAXRequest = false; //GLOBAL VARIABLE

$("#dropdown").unbind('change');
$("#dropdown").bind('change', takeAction);


function takeAction(){

    if(oAJAXRequest != false){
      return;
    }

    event.preventDefault();
    var colour = $('#colors .selected').attr('data-color');
    oAJAXRequest = $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: $(event.currentTarget).val(),
        data : {
          name : $(event.currentTarget).attr('title'),
          colour : colour
        },
        success: function(data) {
            $('#Data').html(response.Data);
            oAJAXRequest = false;
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, sMessage, oException) {
            oAJAXRequest = false;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I changed oAJAXRequest to true.then I only working for the first dropdown change..from next time when I change the dropdown to other value it's simply calling return

Answer (score 0):

I used

```
$('#dropdown').off('change',takeAction);
```

Worked for me.

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information.  The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question.

Comment: djot, I want to answer my question and I answered in answer section